# Not able to render HTML tags inside textarea content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I have a HTML file with textarea input element and the content is fetched from database which includes `<br/>` tags.

My JSON response is:
`NDAs can be "mutual", meaning both parties are restricted in their use of the materials provided, or they can restrict the use of material by a single party. <br /> It is also possible for an employee to sign an NDA or NDA-like agreement with an employer.`

On rendering it is not taking a new line and displaying `<br/>` as it is(taking as static content). 
I used handlebars `{{{content}}}` but not helpful.

Comment: You can't render html into a textarea, but you can force line breaks replacing `<br>` tags by `\n` or `\r`. To be sure, use a regex into replace function:  `yourString = yourString.replace(/\r?\n/g, '')`

Comment: Did you try encoding your HTML? Like `<br>` becomes `&lt;br&gt;`?

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't enter HTML inside a textarea, you can only insert pure text.

You may want to use an editable div (`<div contenteditable="true">...</div>`)

Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: Hi Jack. I tried to apply contenteditable=true for textarea. It is not working. <textarea contenteditable="true"><h3>This is a paragraph. </h3></textarea>

Comment: Hello Archana. As I previously wrote, you can not use a textarea to parse HTML tags, but only plain text. In the example I wrote for you, I used a `div` instead.

Comment: Hey Jack... I dont want the div to be editable. I made it disabled and removed textarea, instead of it , i used a separate div. If i make contenteditable="true", the content i want to display is editable to user, which i dont want. I dint add this attribute also. Now it is working fine with a div disabled. Thank you

Comment: Then you don't have to "disable" a div: just use a div with no particular attributes :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want that your HTML will be rendered, you should use [contenteditable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing `<br />` with `/n`. That should resolve your issue.